# React: POST Fetch request to JSON server results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-server

I am trying to wright an object to a db file using JSON server; however, the JSON server keeps giving the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

I can successfully read for the file using Fetch, its just POST that I'm having this trouble with. Any ideas?

[image: JSON-Server Error message]

```
//this is the function where I perform the POST

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setSubmitted('t');
        setIsPending(true);

        const arg = { filename, trialId, hash, location, author, submitted };
       
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/args/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(arg)
          }).then(() => {
            console.log('new file added');
          })
 
    };

//This is my current db file:

{
    "args": [

        {
            "filename": "Accelerometer",
            "trialId": "01",
            "hash":"",
            "author": "",
            "location": "IPFS",
            "submitted": "f"
        }
    ]
}
```

// This is my fetch that works that I use to read from the db page.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/args', { signal: abortCont.signal })
        .then(res => {
            //check response for error
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error('Error when fetching data');
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            setArgs(data);
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(null);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
                console.log('fetch aborted');
            } else {
                setError(err.message);
                setIsPending(false);
            }
        })
}, 1500);
```

// This is the function Function.createID in the server that seems to be having an issue.

```
function createId(coll) {
  const _ = this;

  const idProperty = _.__id();

  if (_.isEmpty(coll)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    let id = _(coll).maxBy(idProperty)[idProperty]; // Increment integer id or generate string id


    return _.isFinite(id) ? ++id : nanoid(7);
  }
}
```

Comment: Always include text (such as code, stack traces, ...) in code blocks, **not images**.

Comment: Also since the error seems to be happening on the server, why haven't you included the server code that handles the request? _especially the code that the stacktrace points to_

Comment: I have added the code for the function from the server

Comment: What does `coll` and `idProperty` end up being? I assume `_` refers to Lodash?

Comment: createID is used to override lodash-id's